# how to make post request in node js + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make post request using express + node.js .I install these plugins 
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "expressjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.0.47"
  }
}
```

I make post request like that

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var app = express();


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;

// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/abc", function(err, database) {
    if(err) throw err;

    db = database;

    // Start the application after the database connection is ready
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    console.log('---')
    var user_id = req.body.id;
    var token = req.body.token;
    var geo = req.body.geo;

    res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ' + geo);
});
```

When I hit browser **http://localhost:3000/api/users**  like that nothing happen ..

here is screen shot[image]

I also try chrome rest client to sent post request .. I do like that in screen shots .But I did not receive any console message or response from server where i am doing wrong..

I am getting only this message from console
**Listening on port 3000**

[image]

Comment: 1. why is tagged with jquery? 2. you need to make app.get('/' callback()) if you want to display something in the browser

Comment: Visiting it in the browser makes a GET request (you have nothing listening for a GET request). Using the rest client - I believe you need to set the correct Content-Type header, otherwise Express is going to parse it as URL-encoded, not JSON

Comment: I want to check about post not get request

Comment: did you add Content-Type header with value as application/json?

Comment: where it should write waite checking

Comment: done man got ...!! thanks for help

Comment: Post requests shouldn't be used for retrieving information. They *can* be, but it runs counter to general REST principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first picture shows a `GET` request, since the browser defaults to `GET`. Since you don't allow for a `GET` you just a generic error.

With the ReST-client you need to set headers to `Content-Type: application/json`. This then should work.